# HSQLDB - user lacks privilege or object not found: SQLState(42501) vendor code(-5501)

Tags: jdbc, hsqldb

I have migrated from hsqldb_1.8.10 to hsqldb_2.3.2 version but suddenly hsqldb stops working. I tried a lot to solve the issue but could not find the root cause of the issue. I have googled it and got numerous links but nothing could solve my problem.

I have copied the log and script file for reference.

**DriverManager Log**

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://ip_address/database")
trying driver[className=sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver,sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver@1c695a6]
*Driver.connect (jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://ip_address/database)
trying driver[className=org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver,org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver@1386918]
getConnection returning       
driver[className=org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver,org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver@1386918]
SQLState(42501) vendor code(-5501)
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: RESULTS
```

**Database.script** file

`SET DATABASE UNIQUE NAME HSQLDB44D4CB4776
    SET DATABASE GC 0
    SET DATABASE DEFAULT RESULT MEMORY ROWS 0
    SET DATABASE EVENT LOG LEVEL 0
    SET DATABASE TRANSACTION CONTROL LOCKS
    SET DATABASE DEFAULT ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
    SET DATABASE TRANSACTION ROLLBACK ON CONFLICT TRUE
    SET DATABASE TEXT TABLE DEFAULTS ''
    SET DATABASE SQL NAMES FALSE
    SET DATABASE SQL REFERENCES FALSE
    SET DATABASE SQL SIZE TRUE
    SET DATABASE SQL TYPES FALSE
    SET DATABASE SQL TDC DELETE TRUE
    SET DATABASE SQL TDC UPDATE TRUE
    SET DATABASE SQL TRANSLATE TTI TYPES TRUE
    SET DATABASE SQL CONCAT NULLS TRUE
    SET DATABASE SQL UNIQUE NULLS TRUE
    SET DATABASE SQL CONVERT TRUNCATE TRUE
    SET DATABASE SQL AVG SCALE 0
    SET DATABASE SQL DOUBLE NAN TRUE
    SET FILES WRITE DELAY 500 MILLIS
    SET FILES BACKUP INCREMENT TRUE
    SET FILES CACHE SIZE 10000
    SET FILES CACHE ROWS 50000
    SET FILES SCALE 32
    SET FILES LOB SCALE 32
    SET FILES DEFRAG 0
    SET FILES NIO TRUE
    SET FILES NIO SIZE 256
    SET FILES LOG TRUE
    SET FILES LOG SIZE 50
    CREATE USER SA PASSWORD DIGEST 'd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e'
    ALTER USER SA SET LOCAL TRUE
    CREATE SCHEMA PUBLIC AUTHORIZATION DBA
    ALTER SEQUENCE SYSTEM_LOBS.LOB_ID RESTART WITH 1
    SET DATABASE DEFAULT INITIAL SCHEMA PUBLIC
    GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SQL_IDENTIFIER TO PUBLIC
    GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.YES_OR_NO TO PUBLIC
    GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TIME_STAMP TO PUBLIC
    GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CARDINAL_NUMBER TO PUBLIC
    GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CHARACTER_DATA TO PUBLIC
    GRANT DBA TO SA
    SET SCHEMA SYSTEM_LOBS
    INSERT INTO BLOCKS VALUES(0,2147483647,0)`

Comment: It looks like you haven't created any table in your database, but are trying to access one named RESULTS.

Comment: i am calling `new org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcConnection().prepareCall("Select * from RESULTS").execute()` to check for the table existence. if table does not exists, it should return `java.sql.SQLException: Table not found in statement exception`(like hsqldb_1.8.10 does). But in hsqldb_2.3.2, it throws `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: RESULTS`. Is this is the expected behavior in version 2.3.2?

Comment: You're selecting *everything* in a table to check if it exists, and rely on an error message to know if it exists. That's really not what you should do. Read http://hsqldb.10974.n7.nabble.com/HSQLDB-Query-table-names-in-a-database-td2294.html

Answer (score 2):

I was also getting the same error. At last i solved it myself. The issue was because of the incorrect connection url.

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection
             ("jdbc:hsqldb:file:///D:/hsql/testdb;shutdown=true;ifexists=true", "sa", "");
```

Here testdb is the name of the db you are trying to connect. i was using the eclipse data source plugin to connect to hsql. while configuring the same, i have given the database location as D:/hsql/testdb. so that caused the issue.

I was trying to retrieve a table from the testdb, before creating a table in testdb.

Also if you connecting to db using eclipse data source plugin make sure that you have executed `SHUTDOWN` command before running the java application, otherwise it will throw following error

```
Database lock acquisition failure: lockFile:
org.hsqldb.persist.LockFile@d9999e76[file =D:\hsql\testdb.lck, exists=true, locked=false, valid=false, ] 
method: checkHeartbeat read: 2015-09-30 15:09:55 heartbeat - read: -3700 ms
```

Hope this is helpful.